# os.rename deletes randomly files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a roughly 150.000 image files that I need to rename. These are stored on an Unix system and I list the files, use regex to find the bit I want to rename and do the rename. Looking at the output, I find that files have been deleted. If I just replace the os.rename with a print statement, all the files are present and renamed. I tried running the code remotely from a Jupiter notebook and locally with an executable script, same behaviour: random deletion of some of the files. Does anyone have an explanation?
Here is the code

```
import os as os
import re as re

pattern = re.compile('(.*_.*Z0)(\d)(C0\d.tif)')
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file.startswith("08") and not file.endswith("C04.tif"):
        res = re.search(pattern, file)
        zPlane = str(int(res.group(2))-2)
        os.rename(file, res.group(1)+zPlane+res.group(3))
```

and a few file names

```
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z07C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z04C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z05C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z06C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z07C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z04C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z05C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z03C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z06C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z07C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z03C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z03C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z06C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z07C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z03C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z04C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z05C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z06C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z07C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z04C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z05C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z07C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z03C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z04C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z05C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z04C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z05C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z03C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z07C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z07C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z03C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z04C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z05C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z04C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z05C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z03C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z07C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z01C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z02C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z03C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z04C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z05C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z06C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A01Z07C04.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A02Z01C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A02Z02C03.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z01C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z02C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z03C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z06C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z07C02.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z01C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z02C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z04C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z05C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z06C01.tif
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z07C01.tif
```

Comment: ceck if a targetnamed-file of that new name exists before you rename something. if so, change the new name a bit.

Comment: Edit: the exact same code replacing the os.rename with print statement works as advertised. There is no name that exist before, all files are generated by robotic microscopes, there is no human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Store your "some filenames" in a file called f.txt, use:

```
with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    files = set((x.strip() for x in r.readlines()))

import re as re
results = {}
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*_.*Z0)(\d)(C0\d.tif)')
for file in files:
    if file.startswith("08") and not file.endswith("C04.tif"):
        res = re.search(pattern, file)
        zPlane = str(int(res.group(2))-2)

        # overwriting existing file
        newname = res.group(1)+zPlane+res.group(3)
        if newname in files:
            print(newname," overwrites existing file")

        # check if two files get renamed into the same one
        keyy = results.setdefault(newname,[])
        keyy.append( file )

# this outputs nothing
for k in results:
    if len(results[k])>1:
        print(k,results[k])
```

You are overwriting existing files with your renaming. I took them from a text file.

You rename file A into B (which already exists) and then rename B to C when it is processed. This makes it look as if files got deleted.

Output:

```
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z01C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A02Z01C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A04Z01C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z05C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z05C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z04C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z02C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z02C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z03C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z02C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z01C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z04C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z04C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A04Z05C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z03C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z04C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z05C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z05C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z02C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z04C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F002L01A02Z05C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A04Z01C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z05C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A03Z04C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z03C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z01C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A02Z01C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z01C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z04C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F003L01A04Z03C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z01C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A02Z02C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z02C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A02Z04C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F005L01A03Z02C02.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z05C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F010L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F008L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F006L01A04Z02C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F004L01A04Z03C01.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F007L01A02Z03C03.tif  overwrites existing file
08-20-16_01-00-43_G13_T0001F009L01A03Z02C02.tif  overwrites existing file
```

Solution:

```
import os.path

if (os.path.exists(newname)):
    # choose another name ....
```

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks a lot. Your post made me think harder about the data and realise that the renaming creates names that exist already indeed. The easiest to change that is actually to sort the list so that the renaming/renumbering does not create already existing files.